# Improve Query Performance of Select Statment inside IN Statment

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, select, derived-tables, query-performance

My query is:

```
(3) UPDATE wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'outofstock' where meta_key = '_stock_status' and 
    post_id in  
        ( 
         (2)SELECT post_id FROM 
            ( 
            (1) SELECT A.post_id from wp_postmeta A 
                JOIN wp_postmeta B ON A.post_id = B.post_id 
                AND A.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_beden' 
                and A.meta_value in ('12yas','34yas','56yas','78yas','910yas','1112yas') 
                and B.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_renk' 
                and ((B.meta_value = 'bordo') OR ('bordo' = 'hepsi')) 
                JOIN wp_posts ON A.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
                and term_taxonomy_id in ('2643','2304') 
            ) AS DerivedTable
        )
```

To improve the speed of this query, I analysed it using the "Explain" statment. Below are the results:

When I added `explain` to (1) location in above query and run the subquery. The results are as below:

[image]

When I added `explain` to (2) location and run that subqyery, results are as below.

[image]

When I added `explain` to (3) location and run the whole query, results are as below:

[image]

My analysis is there is no speed problem with the (1) subquery, but after I select the data from this subquery to a derived table (2), somehow there is a 55.277.640 "rows" comes, and which seems to be the reason why my query is so slow. How can I optimize it ? What is wrong here ?

**Edit**: The tables are Wordpress WooCommerce module standart tables. I didn't modified them. Here `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results:

**wp_postmeta**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11119572 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**wp_posts**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=352598 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**wp_term_relationships**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Edit2**: After manually changing to innoDB, the explains are changed as below.

Explain in location 1:

[image]

Explain in location 2:

[image]

Explain in location 3:

[image]

Here some information on what I am trying to do. In my website there are a lot of products variations. The wp_postmeta table has meta information for all variations. (For example, price, color, size, instock etc).

My query is used to update stock information. So for example, I have a product with 9 colors, and 9 size. Which means 81 variations. If I need to update stocks of color 'bordo' for all sizes. This means it is 9 rows has to be updated in wp_postmeta. (All sizes for color: bordo).

Here some row numbers if I update above queries to `select count(*)`:

> wp_postmeta has 9.929.761
>
> The first subquery where I indicated as (1), returns 3612 rows.
>
> The first subquery where I indicated as (2), returns 3612 rows as
>   well.
>
> The first subquery where I indicated as (3), returns 3612 rows too.

So basicly there are 3612 "bordo" colored product variations in my website, and I need to update stock information of all these variations.

When I checked my database, there are 227K rows with meta_key "_stock_status". (All colors and all product sizes). I know the cost of updating all that data is a little bit costly. But I am not using this function all the time.

When I add 20 new products and when I get information from production team about latest stock status of products and colors, I click this "Update Stocks" button to update all stock information in the website to the last state.

**Edit2**

I read the modification requirments for wp_postmeta table from Rick. They all seemed to be helpful but I didn't wanted to change the default structure of wp_postmeta table as I am not a DB expert and may not revert back future problems that can be caused by modifing the core wordpress tables.

So to stay on the safe side, I read the other two answers from **ypercubeᵀᴹ** and **Old Pro**.

They suggested to add a new index to wp_postmeta table, and this is my only change on this core wordpress table. After I tested both of their queries, and they gave the same `explain` statement results as below.

[image]

So basicly their query is doing the same thing with different structure. Now the query's performance has increased quite much. The only question in my mind, how safe it is to add a manual index to a wordpress core table?

Comment: It won't affect performance bu that `OR ('bordo' = 'hepsi')` is useless and can be removed.

Comment: It would help us if you posted the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` for all 3 tables in the query. And the version of MySQL.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ updated the question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` for the 3 tables in the query. They are all wordpress - woocommerce plugins standart tables.

Comment: Ewww, just noticed that the tables are MyISAM? Oh. my.

Comment: `OR ('bordo' = 'hepsi')` -- What the heck?

Comment: @RickJames 'bordo' is a variable, and it indicates color. I use 'hepsi' to retrieve all colors. So this OR statment gives me all colors when instead of 'bordo', I send a variable as 'hepsi'.

Comment: @HOY - Notice how the Optimizer still reaches into `B` even though it is not needed?  Technically, this is because the rest of the use of `B` checks that there is some color for the item.  It would be more efficient if you could remove all references to `B` in the query in the 'hepsi' case.

Comment: "How safe it is to add a manual index to a wordpress core table?" I'd say 100%. I can't see how it could break anything. And if (very unlikely) it does break something in the future (say a WP migration that doesn't like the name of the index), you can always drop or rename the index.

Comment: I agree, it is very safe to add an index, although I recommend redefining the existing indexes, which is slightly safer in the case of automated schema changes. Note that ypercube and I are recommending different indexes to add, but you can easily add both by redefining the existing `post_id` and `meta_key` indexes.

Comment: @HOY - Adding an extra index to a table is 'safe'.  It will either help some `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`, or it won't.  It will slow down `INSERTs` a tiny bit, but this is not critical.

Comment: @OldPro - Yes, we are suggesting different indexes.  Mine is the most complex to implement due to the 191 problem.

Answer (score 3):

`postmeta` has inefficient.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859351/why-are-references-to-wp-postmeta-so-slow
for a discussion of what to do about it.  Or: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta or
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248207/simple-sql-query-on-wp-postmeta-very-slow

Comment: Hi Rick, I am happy to see you. Actually you helped me for the same issue on a previous [topic] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854249/optimizing-an-update-sql-query-with-self-joins-and-subqueries). In which you told me that "In some situations, `IN ( SELECT ... )` is much slower because it reevaluates the SELECT for every post_id". This is why I thought that this is something related to my SQL syntax rather than the postmeta itself. I checked the first link you shared. They seems to be helpful, but does it really removes the problem of `IN (SELECT...)` problem that I am suffering ?

Comment: Are there really 5.5M rows and 227K rows for the intermediate results?  If so, my postmeta tips will speed it up, but you may have a much bigger problem -- namely why do you need to update 227K rows??

Comment: @HOY - And... Even if you get past the inefficiencies of the in-select and postmeta, the cost of updating 227K rows is high.  This is because of the need to capture the previous copy of each row incase of a crash and rollback.

Comment: @RickJames Rollback? The tables are MyiSAM ...

Comment: Ouch.  If you crash in the middle of updating 227K rows, _some_ of the rows will be changed; you won't know which.  This is one of several big reasons to move to InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames Hi, I added some more data to my question after moving to innoDB, also my above query just need to update 3612 rows. If I want to update all colors then the number of rows to update will be much higher. But I am tring to improve this specific query to check less rows. I just moved to innoDB, and didn't do the rest of the suggestions in your answer. I'll check them now, but I wanted to update the question during this time, because moving to innodb changed some of the numbers in `explain` statement results.

Comment: @HOY - OK, 3612 is tolerable; it won't take too long.  Glad you are moving to InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames actually I was using godaddy, and migrated to siteground recently. The issue is most possibly caused because godaddy still using MyiSAM, and because I saw that siteground is using InnoDB as default. Godaddy was a terrible experience and they are still not letting me go as I can see. Anyway thank you for guidence, it was helpful really.

Answer (score 2):

First, the Wordpress database design has several flaws as Rick James points out in his answer and the linked ones. The `wp_postmeta` in particular is a common cause of performance problems in many WP installations, as soon they grow enough and have more than a few thousands rows.

Before going the difficult and long road of addressing that, I'll suggest something that might help improving the specific query in the short time:

---

Rewrite the `IN (complex subquery)` to a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE
    ( 
        SELECT A.post_id from wp_postmeta A 
        JOIN wp_postmeta B ON A.post_id = B.post_id 
        AND A.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_beden' 
        and A.meta_value in ('12yas','34yas','56yas','78yas','910yas','1112yas') 
        and B.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_renk' 
        and ((B.meta_value = 'bordo') OR ('bordo' = 'hepsi')) 
        JOIN wp_posts ON A.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
        and term_taxonomy_id in ('2643','2304') 
    ) AS DerivedTable
    JOIN
        wp_postmeta AS upd
    ON
        upd.post_id = DerivedTable.post_id
SET
    upd.meta_value = 'outofstock'
WHERE
    upd.meta_key = '_stock_status' ;
```

and add an index on `wp_postmeta (meta_key(191), post_id)`

Comment: It is useless to have any columns after a prefix; the rest will be ignored.  Think of it this way -- a prefix is essentially a 'range'.

Comment: I wanted to suggest a `(meta_key, post_id)` but the VARCHAR(255) utf8mb4 does not allow it. Correct?

Comment: Yep.  And I give _five_ workarounds [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes); none is perfect.

Comment: I edited (edit number 2) the question based on your answer, you may check it.

Answer (score 1):

While what I am proposing is not necessarily the best idea in the general case, I think for this specific situation you would be better off using nested `IN` clauses rather than the complicated self-join.  Try this:

```
  UPDATE 
        ( 
          SELECT B.post_id FROM wp_postmeta B where B.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_renk' 
                and ((B.meta_value = 'bordo') OR ('bordo' = 'hepsi')) 
                and B.post_id in 
            ( 
              SELECT A.post_id from wp_postmeta A 
                JOIN wp_posts ON A.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                JOIN wp_term_relationships 
                  ON wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
                and term_taxonomy_id in ('2643','2304') 
              WHERE A.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_beden' 
                and A.meta_value in
                     ('12yas','34yas','56yas','78yas','910yas','1112yas') 
            )
        ) AS targets
  JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = targets.post_id
  SET meta_value = 'outofstock' 
  WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

And also, in `wp_postmeta`, replace

```
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
```

with

```
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`, `meta_key`(191)),
```

Comment: Query execution failed, Reason:
SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @HOY sorry, I don't have a system to test these queries on, and forgot that you cannot include the table you are updating in the subquery. I updated my answer to materialize the subquery into a table you can use, just as all the other answers and your original query do. Please try the new query and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I edited (edit number 2) the question based on your answer, you may check it.